# Server tag : The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, server-tags

I got this error and I don't know what's wrong with my code...here it is:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkbtnPDFPreview" Text="Preview" 
  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"productID") %>'                                
  CommandName="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"documentID") %>">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `"` in the attribute value delimiter and *inside* the attribute:

```
CommandName="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"documentID") %>"
```

Change the outer delimiter to `'` as already done for `CommandArgument`:

```
CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"documentID") %>'
```

Comment: Ahhh perfect...I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's this line:

```
CommandName="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"documentID") %>"
```

You did the right thing here!

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"productID") %>'
```